# Changing to a directory named -

Tags: bash, cd

I have a script that traverses the directory tree using `pushd` and `popd`. It is choking on a directory named `-`. I have tried:

```
pushd -- -
```

But the dash is still interpreted as an option (and the previous directory is pushed on the stack). I have the same problem with `cd`.

Comment: i cant help but ask: why is there a directory named "-"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In different flavors, this is an interview question. *(How would I remove a file named "-"?)*

```
$ cd ./-
$ pushd ./-
$ pushd ./$next
$ pushd $PWD/- # Yay JL
$ pushd /what/ever/-
```

Comment: And the other option: `cd /path/to/the/minus/-`